# Grabbing first file from each directory using os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

I am using the following code to extract all files (with same type) in all subdirectories in parent folder.

```
dcm_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for names in files:
        if names.endswith(".dcm"):
            dcm_files.append(os.path.join(root, names))
```

How do I only get the first file from each subdirectories in parent folder ?

Comment: If you mean *first found element*, just break the loop after appending:
`break` after this statement: `dcm_files.append(os.path.join(root, names))`

Comment: What means "first"? The file system may have no particular order of files so it may be a random one delivered first by the OS.

Comment: First file in terms of it's created date?

Comment: @karolch thankyou so much :D

Answer (score 0):

1. you find all the `files`
2. you index the first file from that list `files[0]`